# How to display an image array in VTK

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vtk

I am a newbie to vtk array concepts.
I have a single dimensional array of size **(1127 x 803 x 49)**.It is an image array which consists of **49 images with 1127 rows and 803 columns each.**
The datatype of the array is **uint16** and the byte order is **LittleEndian**.

My question is

1)How i can display this array as 49 separate images using VTK or ITK? or

2)How to display the whole 49 images as a single image using VTK or ITK ? (whichever is efficient **without taking more than 3 or 4 seconds**,so that i can convert it to DICOM image afterwards.)

****What i have tried.****

Since VTK accepts vector,
I have copied the array to `std::vector`

```
      std::vector<uint16_t> valvect;
      valvect.assign(val1, val1 + (1127 * 803 * 49));//where val1 is the 1D array.
```

I have also referenced these links

1. https://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=VtkFloatArray_from_STL_vector
2. [How to visualize 2d array of doubles in vtk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747494/how-to-visualize-2d-array-of-doubles-in-vtk)

   ```
    vtkFloatArray *arr = vtkFloatArray::New();
    arr->SetNumberOfComponents(nComponents);
    arr->SetArray(&this->vec->operator[](0), this->vec->size(), 1);
   ```

But i have no idea how to go further .How can i modify this.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried it using DCMTK library and it is generating the dicom files but the array is not reading properly,Iam getting some grainy images.This is my code.

```
     rrawdatabuffer  //my array of type uint16_t *  
   DcmFileFormat fileformat;
   DcmDataset *dataset = fileformat.getDataset();
   OFCondition status = dataset->putAndInsertUint16Array(DCM_PixelData, 
   rrawdatabuffer, 803*1127*49, false);
   status = fileformat.saveFile("test.dcm", EXS_LittleEndianExplicit);
```

Comment: You probably want to start with a 3D vtkImageData. My advice is to take a look at the examples here: [https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/)

Comment: ***without taking more than 3 or 4 seconds*** Try release mode, in Visual Studio I have seen a case where Debug mode took 100 times longer to execute.

Comment: I have used DCMTK library as i mentioned in my UPDATE  and it is working perfectly.Hope somebody needs it in future ,so iam posting it as an comment.

Comment: DCMTK is a library I use for dicom files along with VTK, ITK and GDCM.